# enumitem-zref: reference items automatically

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, enumitem

I am trying to use the enumitem-zref package in order to reference automatically all item of an enumeration. Here is a simple example (found on the Internet, but seems to agree with the documentation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem,enumitem-zref}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[start=34,label=(\arabic*),name=thelist]
\item stuff
\item more stuff \label{more stuff}
\item yet more
\end{enumerate}

This is \refitem{thelist,35} or \refitem{thelist{35}}
and this is also \refitem{more stuff}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I can't make it work; I get the following error (extract of the log from pdflatex):

```
...
Package zref Info: New property list: zen@list on input line 108.
Package zref Info: New property: zen@ on input line 110.
Package zref Info: New property: zen@page on input line 117.
...
Package zref Info: New property: zen@counter on input line 135.
! Package zref Error: Property `zen@default,zen@page,zen@type,zen@depth,zen@lis
tctr,zen@listname,zen@index,zen@label,zen@ref,zen@starlabel,zen@parents,zen@ref
item,zen@commaref,zen@item,zen@currentlabel,zen@counter' does not exist.
See the zref package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

I tried small changes (including zref explicitly, changing order of inclusions...), without success. I don't know if the problem can come from my configuration (pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Arch Linux)). I could not find any equivalent package, and neither could I write a simple workaround (I'm quite new to LaTeX). All I want is to be able to write something like:

```
\begin{enumerate}[name=mylist,label=\arabic*.]
   \item First item;
   \item Second item;
      \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
        \item first subitem,
        \item second subitem,
        \item third subitem;
      \end{enumerate}
   \item Third item.
\end{enumerate}
```

all items being automatically referenced (for example by `item:mylist.1`, `item:mylist.2`, `item:mylist.2.1`, `item:mylist.2.2`, etc.), so that `\ref{item:mylist.2.3}` displays an hyperrlink "2.(c)", or something similar.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suspect a bad bug in `enumitem-zref`.

Comment: Then maybe I should report this to the author...

Comment: I voted to close because it's a bug of the package.